# Why is bash using -ge to compare instead of ==?

Tags: linux, bash, conditional-statements

So I'm looking at adding a low hard drive space warning to my home server. I like the look of the following which comes from [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-send-email-alert-when-your-disk-space-gets-low):

```
ADMIN="yourmail@example.com"
# set alert-level 90 % standard
ALERT=10
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $6 }' | while read output;
do
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
  if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then
    echo "space low on \"$partition ($usep%)\", on server $(hostname) at $(date)" |
 mail -s "Alert: Free space low, $usep % used on $partition" $ADMIN
  fi
done
```

As I find it prudent to understand any script you run before actually running it I have been looking at the man pages to work out how each of the individual sections of the program works and it seems fairly straight forward. The only thing I don't understand is the `-ge` flag in the `if` conditional statement. According to the bash [introduction to if page](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) these would both evalute to true if the "file exists". How does this logic pass true when I am comparing two variables. In other programming languages I would use `==` syntax. Similarly why are we comparing the values of `90` (as reported by df) to `10` which is the variable of `ALERT`, I assume this has something to do with the way the conditional evaluates? I have no reason to believe that this code won't work I just would like to know why before adding it to a script.

Thanks.

Comment: In this context the -ge means greater than or equal to. See the last paragraph here : http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

Comment: What does the echo line say it is doing?

Comment: @Argonauts seems I didn't scroll down far enough excellent thanks

Comment: Maybe it's not bash, maybe it's sh/dash (I don't _think_ dash uses `==`)